# sd card write on Windows 10 Pro 64 failed

Tags: pi-2, sd-card, windows

I try to write my RaspI SD Card on win10 using **Etcher-Setup-1.4.4-x64.exe** and **2018-04-18-raspbian-stretch-lite.img** image.

Write and verify looks good, but Raspi 2 Model B don't boot. I get no error. Before I use this SD Card with Windows 7. This works well...

Some files SD-Card looks damaged (strange file name chars...)
[image]

SD Card write on Win10 don't work?

Comment: sd card write on win10 does work - try downloading the img again, it could be a corrupt image (check using 7-zip, it can open the img and then open the FAT image, the filenames should look correct)

Comment: @JaromandaX . You are right. Windows defalt Zip down work. Using 7-Zip the image could be flash to the SD card and Raspi come up..!